# Windows server 2016 restarts every night around 02:50

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016

We have a Windows 2016 Server installed over Dell R430 server.
In the last month, the server suddenly does an unplanned restart (looks like the server losts power).

The error message after the restart is :

> The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly.

There is no further information in the bug cache DMP files - it only says the `hal.sys` driver crashed (it's for hardware to speak with the OS).

Please help us. How should we collect information to understand what may be the reason for these restarts? Or can you even provide the reason for it?

Comment: Is it connected to a UPS? If so, anything set up in the UPS application?

Comment: In many countries, electrical current changes in amperage during the night. Electricity is cheaper, due to lower demand during the night, and the power that's supplied is therefore inferior to that you get during the day. Your machine or the UPS it receives power through could have trouble handling the lower power frequency this lower amperage provokes. You should check with your IT or Accounting departments for changes in the contract between your electricity supplier and your company. What you describe is most likely an electrical problem, not a technical one.

Comment: If you use an UPS already: did you run the [hardware diag](https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-us/sln283546/how-to-run-hardware-diagnostics-on-your-poweredge-server?lang=en) and what was the result? Also please post a [DSU](https://www.dell.com/support/article/de-de/sln310654/dell-emc-system-update-dsu?lang=en) screenshot to see if firmware and drivers were updated.

Comment: Instead of believing the datacenter about UPS, you should ask them for [iDRAC](https://www.dell.com/support/article/de-de/sln305828/poweredge-how-to-generate-servers-logs-with-the-idrac?lang=en) access and check the logs - or install [OMSA](https://www.dell.com/support/article/de-de/sln170723/how-to-install-openmanage-server-administrator-omsa-on-windows?lang=en) and check the system logs there for power failures